# Why are division signs in this block of code being treated as regex?

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I have some Javascript code including a few division operators, but Sublime Text's syntax highlighter for Javascript is treating  them as if they were the beginnings and ends of regular expressions. This makes it hard to read the code for the rest of the page, since it causes highlighting problems for all lines below this one.

Here is the code causing the problem:

```
if (-(keyframes[i].objects[j].rotation.x / (Math.PI / 180)) !== 0 || (keyframes[i].objects[j].rotation.y / (Math.PI / 180)) !== 0 || (keyframes[i].objects[j].rotation.z / (Math.PI / 180)) !== 0) {
    if (currentArmorstandObj.wasVillager[0].length > 0) {
        rotationNBT = 'Rotation:[' + (-(keyframes[i].objects[j].rotation.y / (Math.PI / 180))) + 'f,' + (keyframes[i].objects[j].rotation.x / (Math.PI / 180)) + 'f],';
    } else {
        rotationNBT = 'Pose:{Head:[' + (keyframes[i].objects[j].rotation.x / (Math.PI / 180)) + 'f,' + -(keyframes[i].objects[j].rotation.y / (Math.PI / 180)) + 'f,' + -(keyframes[i].objects[j].rotation.z / (Math.PI / 180)) + 'f]},';
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of how it appears in Sublime Text (with Flatland Monokai theme):
[image]

Comment: If you're concerned about readability how about caching some of those values into local variables.

Comment: To be completely fair, how would you tell the difference between `/ (Math.PI /` being a regex compared to two division symbols? In any case, as Evan points out, that is a monstrosity of an `if` statement; you should consider breaking it down.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol—it can't be a RegExp as a RegExp literal is a primary expression and would need to be wrapped in brackets to appear as part of another primary expression. The Sublime Text parser is just not up to the job (apparently).

Comment: what version of Sublime Text are you using? looks fine for me in 3118 with the default Monokai color scheme